# Should I get an owner's manual or repair manual?

Tags: repair, lexus, service-manual

I'm new to working on cars as I have only done a few minor repairs/maintenance myself in the last year.  I intend to start doing most if not all the maintenance on my car in the future.  I've been learning online, but I am wondering if it is worth it to get the owner's manual for my car or a repair manual?

- Are either necessary?
- Are both necessary?
- Should I get one or the other?

My car is a 2003 Lexus RX300 and I've been looking at ordering the owner's manual on Ebay or just getting the Hayne's repair manual.  Any insight on what is good to have would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Owners Manual is only a basic operations manual. Not worth paying for (did you not get one with the car?)

The Haynes Manual is a good starting point if you want to do any work on your car. As you get more advanced, you'll want to get a copy of the Shop Manual; this is the gospel that the dealer mechanics work from (or should work from..). Much much more detail than the Haynes manual. Definitely worth getting, in my opinion.

Comment: Got the car used and there was no manual.  I'll look into the Shop Manual.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The repair manual usually includes most or all of the information in the user's manual (at least in VW Auto Group).

In my experience, for someone having an account on auto forums or even this site, it's worth it.